# Docker-Compose cant reach my http from network

Tags: nginx, networking, docker-compose, configuration

tried a lot of tutorials but failed. Maybe I miss some knowledge.

My Problem: I use docker-compose and create several containers for mysql, adminer, nginx and php. But, I am not able to connect from my mobile phone (same network) to the website published by nginx.

Thats my docker-compose (Removed all tries):

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: r00t
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mosys_tools
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'pass'

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15.3-alpine
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - "./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro"
      - "./application:/usr/src/app"
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    depends_on:
      - php

  php:
    volumes:
      - "./application:/usr/src/app"
      - "./temporary/composer/cache:/.composer/cache"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    env_file:
      - .env
    user: 1000:1000
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=192.168.178.41 remote_timeout=30
```

Comment: Is your host (PC running docker) allowing requests for outside? How are you making requests from the phone to the host? Have you try to open ports (add Firewall rules) and use the Host's ip address?

Comment: @abestrad I a doing the request by browser entering the IP (http://192.168.178.15). No idea on linux how to restrict or allow requests from outside or open ports. (MINT 18, Ubuntu)

Comment: First make sure your Host OS is allowing requests in those particular ports, (Check your windows firewall or antivirus if applies)

Comment: @abestrad It is LINUX, on windows I never had problems to do it.